# Static content deploy odd behaviour

Tags: magento2

I have Magento 2.1.4 and recently attempted to upgrade an extension but afterwards whenever I deploy the static content, it loses the CSS/JS on the front and backends.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I have noticed that the path to my CSS is for example (I have turned the versioning folder thing off)...

```
/pub/static/frontend/mytheme/themename/en_GB/css/styles-l.css
```

However when I look for the folder above, en_BG does not exist. It is 'en_US' instead.

The same sort of behaviour is the same for the backend. The path to the CSS says...

```
/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css
```

But when I look for that file, 'en_US' does not exist. 'en_GB' exists instead.

If I just rename the folders and make sure they exist it works fine, but my question is why would this be happenning?

The site is setup to be en_GB (United Kingdom)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have grunt installed? Or someway to compile the less files?

Comment: I dont unfortunately - if I could set that up can you tell me what/where I should be looking? Thanks

Comment: Our normal routine consist of using grunt to compile the css/less files and then we use the di:compilers. 

Check this link for some more helpful information. 
[link]http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow these commands**

```
cd var
rm -rf *
cd ../pub/static/
rm -rf *
cd ../..
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US
```